# Highly reusable react component without any code change and use only properties

Tags: reactjs

I would like to create a component which I can reuse also for other projects without any code change (only by passing different properties). 
A small example: 
I have a login form which has a username input and a password input which can look for example like this:

```
class Login extends Component {

   static propTypes = {
    login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    defaultEmailValue: PropTypes.string,
    defaultPasswordValue: PropTypes.string,
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    const username = this.refs.username;
    const password = this.refs.password;
    this.props.login(username.value, password.value);
  };


  render() {
    const {
      defaultEmailValue,
      defaultPasswordValue,
      } = this.props;

    return (
      <form method="post">
        <input defaultValue={defaultEmailValue} ref="username" type="email" />
        <input defaultValue={defaultPasswordValue} ref="password" type="password" />
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the minimal version of a login form, but what to do when I want to extend the render function to add container components like this (added column  tags):

```
class Login extends Component {

   /*....*/

  render() {
    const {
      defaultEmailValue,
      defaultPasswordValue,
      } = this.props;

    return (
      <form method="post">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <input defaultValue={defaultEmailValue} ref="username" type="email" />
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <input defaultValue={defaultPasswordValue} ref="password" type="password" />
           </div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Therefore I have always to modify the render function. Is there a good possibility to do this only with properties? 
I estimated to do this with a Wrapper-Component over the Login component but then I have always rewrite the complete render function. 
The next possible solution I thought about is to pass wrapper component classes through properties which can be rendered. But is this so a good solution or is this bad practice?

Unfortunately, I found no real solution for this tutorial in the internet and therefore I try it here. Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a good possibility to do this only with properties?

**Representational Components** are exactly for this kind of things.

```
export default const LoginForm = (/**props**/ {username, email, submitHandler, errors}) => {
  return (
     <form>
       {/* as usual */}
     </form>
  )
}
```

use in your ContainerComponent:

```
...
render() {
  return (
    <div className="loginWrapper">
       <LoginForm ...this.props ...this.state ...whatever username="pete" />
    </div>
  )
}
...
```

Comment: Therefore the render function (and its layout structure) has always be hardcoded. Thank you! :-)